# Unable to add styles to tab (bar) and tab (pane) in QT tab widget

Tags: c++, qt, tabs, styles

I am adding Tabs to TabWidget dynamically from the constructor. I have been able to add the tab but have been unable to set the style for the Pane, Tab for the widget.

How do I add styles to tab (bar) and tab (pane)? The names of the tabs are dynamic and not static. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap httpPix(":/rec/img/http_2.png");
    ui->menuTabWidget->addTab(new Workspace(), QString("Projects"));
    ui->menuTabWidget->addTab(new HistoricalRequests(), QString("History"));
    ui->apiTabWidget->setStyleSheet("{background:#FFF}");
    //ui->apiTabWidget->setPalette(*(new QPalette(Qt::green)));
    //ui->apiTabWidget->tabBar()->setPalette(*(new QPalette(Qt::white)));
    ui->apiTabWidget->addTab(new APITab(), httpPix, QString("New Test 1"));
}
```

Comment: [This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtabwidget-and-qtabbar) might provide some useful info.

Comment: The stylesheet string does not look correct. See that doc above.

Comment: Ok tried this not working with static styles. Tried putting the whole stylesheet to the setSetssheet. Not working either. Seems i am stuck here

Answer (score 1):

This is copied straight from production code style sheet that styles tabs. Unfortunately I can't share screenshots but it works most def!

Please note that `MaintenanceBaseWActivity` is the name of one window in the application so that these styles will only work on tabs in that window.

```
MaintenanceBaseWActivity .QTabBar::tab {
background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
stop: 0.0 #666,
stop: 1.0 #aaa );
color: white;
padding: 0.4em;
margin:0;
height:1em;
min-width:5.7em;
max-width:5.7em;
width:5.7em;
border:0px;
border-top-left-radius:8px;
border-top-right-radius:8px;
}

MaintenanceBaseWActivity .QTabBar::tab:selected {
background-color: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
stop: 0.0 #bbb,
stop: 1.0 #ddd);
font-weight:bold;
color:black;
}

/*
MaintenanceBaseWActivity .QTabWidget::tab-bar {
width:1024px;
}
*/

MaintenanceBaseWActivity .QTabWidget::pane {
border-top: 8px solid #ddd;
}
```

EDIT: To answer your comment, I found that setting individual stylesheets per widget is not recommended. Better to name your widgets or at least style classes (you can use object names) in a central stylesheet and then apply that at startup.

Here is the exact code I use to apply the central stylesheet from a resource in my project:

```
QString fileToString(QString fn)
{
    QFile file(fn);
    if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        return in.readAll();
    }
    return "";
}


// Get the core app first
QCoreApplication *capp=static_cast<QCoreApplication *> QCoreApplication::instance());
// Then see if we can get a normal app (with UI and styles)
QApplication *app=qobject_cast<QApplication *>(capp);
if (nullptr!=app) {
    // I am using a resource, so I just make bloody sure it is loaded (since this code might run from palces in the program that might not have resources loaded yet.
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(style);  //My resource file is called "style.qrc" so please adapt this to whatever you are using.
    // Time to load and set the stylesheet program wide. Please replace the path to the stylesheet you want, 
    app.setStyleSheet ( fileToString(":/style/style.qss"));
}
```

Comment: No issues. I understand the styling. What i was not able to get working is how to apply these style programatically from c++ code. I ciuld change the details using the wytles i have

Comment: I added some code. My recommendation after working with this for a while is NOT to set individual styles, but rather maintain one central style sheet that is applied on application startup. Actually you can reload itany time, and I have loaded it on "file change" before which is nice when editing the styles (no need to recompile). Then simply use class names to refer to individual widgets/widget classes.

Comment: Thanks. That was nice of you. I was doing the mistake you pointed out. Do you have any suggestions for folder structures or code organization or modular isolation for a simple to little complex qt application along with the stylesheet comment?

Comment: A few tips maybe. One is to have many resource files instead of one. Try to collect resources that change often in separate files. For example I keep stylesheet alone in its own resource file. This really helps cut down build times, as only changed resources need to be repackaged. Where you keep resources isnt that important. I just have a folder called resources with one subfolder per resource file. When it comes to classes, I found most widgest are styled similarly across the app so widget class names are perfect css selectors. I would set individual object names for tve exception cases.

Comment: Final tip, css selectors can be combined so you can do .MyWindow .MyWidget .MySubWidget QLabel to select all labels in all instances of class mysubwindow inside all inatances of mywidget i side all instances of mywindow. To select object name, simply use hash like this #OneParticularWidgetNamedThis